# Visual Studio Online: How do I pull down from multiple repositories in the same build?

Tags: visual-studio, continuous-integration, teamcity, azure-devops, visual-studio-2015

I setup a build in Visual Studio Online:

[image: CI Build repositories tab]

I keep my application code and application configuration in two separate repositories namely **ZoneLighting** and **ZoneLightingTestConfig**. In the Repository dropdown pictured above, I can only select one of these two repositories. Is there any way to select both so that both repositories will be pulled down into the same folder and the application will be built and tested using both the code and the config? Teamcity has this functionality built-in and I was trying to replicate my setup in Teamcity on VSO. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: It sounds like I can maybe do it with a batch script as a build step, but if I have a script that says `git pull <repo url>`, will it be run in the same folder as the checkout folder? I'm thinking this may be the only approach at the moment.

Comment: Why use separate repositories and not separate branches or folders within the same repository?

Comment: I keep my production configuration under a password-protected repository, so that I can have access to it from anywhere with my credentials. These are then pulled down and deployed with my artifacts to the production server. I looked into password-protecting branches but that's not supported by git. How do you mean by using folders within the same repository?

Comment: Sorry, not a git person. In TFS I would simply apply different access to different folders. That access control would be duplicated automatically when a branch is made. Are you saying that only the configuration repository is password protected?

Comment: Yes my code is open-source but I keep all the configuration like ports and connection strings under a password-protected repository. In Teamcity you can set to pull files from multiple repositories into the same checkout folder and then proceed with the build steps. Is there another standard way to do what I'm trying to achieve? Basically I would like to have code be pulled from my code repository and somehow have the checkout folder be populated with the configuration, but I'd like to keep that configuration private because it contains passwords and other sensitive information.

Comment: The TFS way would be what I said: one repository, with access controls on the various parts.

Comment: Ah okay. Yeah I'll have to research how to do that in git. As far as I know it's not possible to do that in git because you would need to put branches under  password protection.